# How to extract message attributes from AWS SNS Notification?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am writing a small node-express app that has a POST endpoint that is set to receive Amazon SNS notifications. I have done everything that is needed to receive SNS Notifications.

After reading [Using Amazon SNS Message Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html) it seems that the Message Attributes set when publishing to a topic can be extracted and used. However I cannot see the Message attributes in the notifications I receive. Is it advisable to depend on data set in message attributes?

Or should we never try and extract message attributes because they are used for other purposes such as subscription filter policies perhaps?